# How do I load an external file and make sure that it runs first in JSFiddle?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-ajax, jsfiddle

I have a JsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/deeptechtons/rEzW5/2/), and added Microsoft AJAX to be loaded through external JS/resource section. How can I tell whether or not my JS code is run after the AJAX file has finished loading?

Seems that the AJAX does not load either. :(

Here is the code in the JSFiddle:

```
Type.registerNamespace("Tutorial.Chapter1");
Tutorial.Chapter1.Person = function(firstName, lastName) {
    this._firstName = firstName;
    this._lastName = lastName;
};
Tutorial.Chapter1.Person.prototype = {
        set_firstName: function(value) {
            this._firstName = value;
        },
        get_firstName: function() {
            return this._firstName;
        },
        set_lastName: function(value) {
            this._lastName = value;
        },
        get_lastName: function() {
            return this._lastName;
        },
        _firstName: "",
        _lastName: "",
        displayName: function() {
            alert("Hi! " + this._firstName + " " + this._lastName);
        }
    };
Tutorial.Chapter1.Person.registerClass("Tutorial.Chapter1.Person", null);
```

Comment: Couldn't you just paste the MS code after yours instead of using the Add Resources option?

Comment: Why do you need to do this anyway?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Open "Add Resources" section and add the url of your external script...

Comment: also for external css links

Answer (score 20):

The External Resources tab of jsFiddle is currently somewhat tricky and unstable to use. 
The resources defined here are often not correctly included into the code. There seems to be an issue with the automatic recognition of JS and CSS resources. If this happens, the external resource is simply not added to the head section of the resulting code. You can check that by reviewing the source code of the Result frame of your jsFiddle. You will find that your MS AJAX resource is simply NOT mentioned in the resulting HTML code.

The correct recognition can actually be forced by adding a dummy value to the resource's URL like this (see –>[jsFiddle docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/basic/introduction.html#external-resources) for more info):

```
...&dummy=.js
```

Here is an example that shows how to add the external Google Maps API resource to a jsFiddle (mind the *dummy* parameter at the very end!):

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&dummy=.js
```

Unfortunately this won't work for you as the MS AJAX URL will fail when additional parameters are appended.

A solution (and currently the safest way to load external resources) is to avoid the External Resources tab altogether and load external code manually in the first line(s) of jsFiddle's HTML window like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/3.5/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
```

Here is your jsFiddle modified to use that method:  http://jsfiddle.net/rEzW5/12/

It actually does not do a lot (I did not check what is wrong with the rest of your code), but at least it does not throw JavaScript errors anymore.

Comment: I believe it is enough to do `#.js` at the end of the url too, at least in the current version of JSFiddle. Perhaps assets that don't like additional query parameters would play nicer w/ that.

Comment: Unfortunately nowadays this approach no longer seems to work. If you manually try to load JavaScript code it won't work, but instead displays the message "For JavaScript use the panel below or the Resources panel for external files."

Answer (score 1):

@Jpsy's approach no longer seems to work (see my comment under his answer).

For me, adding the resource under External Resources also didn't work. (According to the Firefox Debugger, it couldn't find the resource).

The only way I was able to get an external bit of JavaScript code (in my case jquery.backstretch.js) to work, was to use Google to find a Fiddle which used this resource (and worked), then Fork this Fiddle and copy/paste all my code into the HTML, CSS and JavaScript panels. Ugh!

Answer (score 0):

@clayRay, You absolutely went thru a code surgery. Just resolved that by mentioning external source in plain html which in my case is

```
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
```

Using External Resources tab didn't help a bit...