# How to load KnockoutJS in JSFiddle

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jsfiddle

I've tried to load Knockout in my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrFox1/9hc36310/4/) through an [external reference and script element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790943/how-do-i-load-an-external-file-and-make-sure-that-it-runs-first-in-jsfiddle). In both cases the whole page gets stuck and keeps loading.

Although it's interesting that it does load the html elements and show the error: "ReferenceError: ko is not defined".

That suggests that the executor does continue after the script load.

```
<script type='text/javascript' src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There exists a preset. In the JavaScript editor, click the JavaScript  button, and select KnockoutJS from "Frameworks & extensions".

1:

[image: Screenshot 1]

2:

[image]